# RTMFP .NET Server

Tags: .net, rtmfp

Where i can find any RTMFP .NET server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenRTMFP / Cumulus project is not .Net, but is open source, so a .net version may not be too far away. see http://github.com/openrtmfp/cumulus for details.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere at the moment. No RTMFP specification is currently available - Adobe is keeping it under wraps. Alas, it would be very difficult for anyone to start developing RTMFP servers as one would either need a good specification or reverse-engineer the protocol in question.

Comment: I have found C++ Server https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus
Working good for me.

Comment: In that case, I urge you to post your comment as an answer here - it's not forbidden to answer your own questions, and stackoverflow functions as a question-answer database anyway - other people will want to look it up.